# understanding MITM attack

Tags: certificates, cryptography, diffie-hellman

hi Everyone please correct me if im wrong for my understanding for the man in the middle attack used in a variant of diffie hellman key exchange .

am i right to say that a protocol is susceptible to the man in the middle attack, if each participants is having their own private key of yP and public key of g^yP mod p and

A -> B : g^rA mod P

B -> A : g^rB mod P

​

rA and rB are random values each session and my shared key is = g^rAxB + g^rBxA mod P. This can be attack because the protocol does not authenticate participants .

am i right for that understanding ? and an adversary can just participate in that key exchange ?

Comment: In short: you are right in that DH itself has no protection against MITM. In detail: possible duplicate of [Is Diffie–Hellman key exchange protocol vulnerable to man in the middle attack?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/184248/is-diffie-hellman-key-exchange-protocol-vulnerable-to-man-in-the-middle-attack), [Why can't I MitM a Diffie-Hellman key exchange?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91699/why-cant-i-mitm-a-diffie-hellman-key-exchange).

Comment: Hmm, this is a special version of DH. Not that it matters of course, but that isn't in the answer you've linked to.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no authentication of at least party then then no connection can be trusted, and MitM is possible. MitM does of course require an active attack; just eavesdropping is not enough, and unauthenticated DH does protect against eavesdropping attacks.

Note that the authentication may require a relatively low amount of data (e.g. there are protocols that simply use vicinity) but some kind of authentication does need to take place.